# always pull from origin develop

Tags: git

I have a live test server, and when I type git pull I'd like it to pull from origin develop instead of origin master by default (the live production server pulls by default from origin master).  I don't want to have to type it every time.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40739305/default-behaviour-of-git-pull

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553786/how-do-i-alias-commands-in-git also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the upstream tracked branch to `develop` by running the following command. Then every time it'll pull from `develop`.

```
git branch --set-upstream-to origin/develop
```