# How to discover the current default behavior for git pull?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, default, git-pull

I've started receiving this warning at VS Code startup:

[image]

So I downloaded Git for Windows v2.27.0. Upon running the installer, I encountered this prompt:

[image]

I'd like to choose the same default behavior that Visual Studio did when it first installed Git for me, so as to keep everything working smoothly. I'm enough of a novice at Git that I wouldn't want things to go awry.

I haven't proceeded yet; I don't want to risk mucking it up.

[This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40739305/722393) discusses the concept but doesn't quite get there on finding out what the default is. The [official documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) comes up short here as well.

Is there a way to determine the current default?

If there isn't, is it possible to change the default after the fact, in case I choose the wrong option?

Comment: Default is `Default` on your screenshot. `git pull` by default fetches the remote branch and tries to merge it. If it's fast-forward, then you won't see any merge commit, otherwise you will have one.

Comment: Perhaps if I actually *ran* a `git pull`, would that tell me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[edit] I just re-ran the installer on Windows :

If you have an existing `.gitconfig`, the installer checks it ; keeping the selected option *is* preserving your existing config.

---

Look at your two config variables `pull.rebase` and `pull.ff`

From a terminal :

```
git config --global pull.rebase
git config --global pull.ff
```

or open the `.gitconfig` file in your home directory

- if pull.rebase is set to 'true' : that's the second option
- if pull.ff is set to 'only' : that's the third option
- else : that's the first option

Comment: OP is talking about Windows and integration with VS Code. Are you sure it makes Git visible to the system via `PATH`?

Comment: There's nothing in `.gitconfig` except my name and email address under `[user]`. Also, neither terminal command produces any output. Just to clarify, would this mean the 'else' from your bullet list?

Comment: If something were to go south in that context, I believe that'd call for a new question. Don't you agree? | @0andriy

Comment: @InteXX : yes, it's the 'else' case (the default one actually)

Answer (score 2):

The answer by LeGEC is essentially correct, but this can be addressed more simply:

The "true" default behavior is, as indicated in your screenshot, "ff or merge".  No credible 3rd-party tool will have changed this without asking (or at a BARE minimum notifying) the user, because "rebase" is regarded as a potentially dangerous option and "ff only" breaks some very basic, very common workflows.

If that doesn't seem convincing, then checking the config is the best way to tell for sure, but something I would add to that:

The config may not seem to have relevant settings.  That means either (1) You looked at a specific config file, but the config is being drawn froma different source (git has a layered config scheme), or (2) the default is in use.  It's probably (2), but to avoid ambiguity if you're going to check the config you want to use the `git config` command so that you're seeing things exactly as git sees them when running commands.  Of course that means you must be able to access the `git` command for teh installation in question.

Which leads to one additional option: if you can remember (or, using the history, check) your experiences with the repo, then you can possibly figure out what seeings were in use.  For example:

Do you ever see merge commits with comments like "merged origin/dev into local branch dev" or something similar?  If so, you're using the default options.

Does a pull ever fail due to a non-fast-forward condition?  Then you're using option 3.

Is your history suspiciously more linear than could possibly be real?  Is it also littered with commits here and there that don't build properly and you're not sure why, because you're sure you only commit working states?  If so then either (1) you've been manually rebasing as part of your workflow (you'd know if that's the case), or (2) you're using the 2nd option.

Comment: Thank you, Mark, I appreciate it. Here's the rub: I'm a solo dev, and so I don't use `git pull` except in the rarest of circumstances. (Shucks, I don't even do PRs!) But I'm confident from all of this (yes, I ran the terminal commands—no output) that my VS installation used the default behavior when it initially installed git.